# Selenium - Testing Server For Multiple Sites

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, browser-automation

http://www.seleniumhq.org/ - Selenium is a website/page testing platform I'm interested in using for the following situation:

> *I look after several HTML/CSS/JAVA websites that have forms for the purpose of submitting a query to an SQL database. These queries on the sites return an estimated cost. What I need to do on a daily basis is run test data through these forms to test each system is returning the correct information and it displays correctly to the user.*

What I have in place at the moment is a Windows machine with Selenium IDE + Firefox and a series of Scripts (one for each website) that I run sequentially each day.

The issue I have with this is the more websites I look after, the more tests I have to carry out and as a result, the more time it takes out of my day.

Is there a way I can simply on one machine run multiple tests, i.e. using

- Firefox to carry out these scripts either automatically one after another or
- Again Firefox to carry out these scripts simultaneously again on one machine

I see a lot of documentation that gives me bits of what I'm looking for in different languages like c# java python but none have really what I'm looking for.

Correct me if I'm mistaken here but, surely this kind of test to submit multiple forms for testing purposes should be a very common request in with this software?

Comment: > like c# java python but none have really what I'm looking for.  . greetings, can you please specify what do you mean by that? As i understand you want an automated testing environment without writing any code ? Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Now we're talking :)

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you for your reply :) sorry for the confusion there, I do not mind doing some coding as I have used Python in the past to do some coding for projects, and know little Java. What I'm interested to find out is the layout I might need to put this software together in a Windows environment to achieve an almost automated multiple estimate website query. I must admit I am rather confused with hugely varied guides and examples available across various websites. Does this answer your question? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about here, is a classic "autotesting stack". It is divided on several parts, starting from the bottom (talking about Java here):

1. The system you're testing (a website you want to test)
2. Driver (Selenium Webdriver)
3. Your tests (recorder with Selenium or written manually)
4. Framework for running your tests (JUnit or TestNG)
5. Build manager (read below)
6. Continuous integration server (read below)

I fuppose that at the moment, you already have stepsfrom 1-4 covered, so let's focus on 5 and 6.

As 2 most popular build managers there  are:
[Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)and/or Ant m they allow you to build your various tests all together and run them trough the console. You can set up the scheduling (also using the console).

Talking about the continuous integration server, it will also allow you to run all your tests (builds them using MAven or Ant) in paralel. There you will have a GUI, where you will be able to schedule various tests for different websites. The tool i was using: [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/).

With all those steps, you will have all your testing environment set up and working smoothly. Hope that this brought some light to your question